# How are languages specified in a Windows 8 package?

Tags: windows-8

I have the following issue: I am trying to submit an app to the Windows 8 store, using the token I received during an app excellence lab. In the Description tab of the process, I see that apart from the United Kingdom language which I have specified as a market, I also get a Greek language support. So now I have to specify a greek description, together with all other metadata, screenshots etc. for this language. I do not wish to do that however, since it will fail certification for incomplete metadata (there is no screenshot with a greek caption in my app, as the certification demands).

So the question is, how did the store detect from the app package that my app supports Greek, and how do I remove it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wasn't too difficult after all. From Visual Studio->Select project->Properties->Default language